# Managing different stages with one webserver and two worker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow

I am currently setting up my airflow environment at AWS. I would like to load all dags in the webserver from both my development and master branch. I sync them on changes to two different S3 buckets which I mount to the EC2 instance. My idea is to load the dags using a dag bag loader as described [here](https://medium.com/@xnuinside/how-to-load-use-several-dag-folders-airflow-dagbags-b93e4ef4663c) for loading dags from two different folders. Two distinguish between them in the webserver each python file checks its current folder and sets the owner in the default_args to the stage. Additionally the stage is set as queue and the corresponding worker picks it up.

The problem is the implementation: Loading the dags works, but if I import an external python file from a subfolder in the dag that will be executed there, I get an error that the module cannot be found. I guess this due to the fact that the dag loader loads the dags and the current working directory is the airflow home folder. The external python files that are loaded in the dags are still in the other folders that are mounted from s3.

As you can see in the Dockerfile, the airflow home folder is:

```
/usr/local/airflow
```

My code structure is as follows in the previous directory:

```
/dags
  add_dag_bag.py

/stages/staging/dags
  test_dag.py
  /scripts
    external_test.py

/stages/production/dags
  test_dag.py
  /scripts
    external_test.py
```

The add_dag_bag.py looks as follows:

```
from airflow.models import DagBag
import os

dags_dirs = ['/usr/local/airflow/stages/staging/dags', '/usr/local/airflow/stages/production/dags']
for dir in dags_dirs:
    dag_bag = DagBag(os.path.expanduser(dir))
    if dag_bag:
        for dag_id, dag in dag_bag.dags.items():
            print(dag_id)
            globals()[dag_id] = dag
```

In the `test_dag.py` I import some python callable from the scripts folder such as `from scripts.external_test import callable`.

The dag is not loaded in the web interface while I can see the following error in the logs: `No module named scripts.external_test`

Any ideas how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `PYTHONPATH` to the dag home folder? Something like `PYTHONPATH=../../dags python3 external.py`

Comment: I am using this docker image to run airflow https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/Dockerfile where I have added an ENV that contains all paths `PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/airflow:/usr/local/airflow/stages/staging:/usr/local/airflow/stages/production`. As you can see in the Dockerfile, the home path is /usr/local/airflow

Comment: Can you provide more details and specific codes to make the problem reproducible?

Comment: I have added more details to my initial post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing more research but have not found a solution yet. Maybe I am still missing some configuration. I have looked into [packaged DAGs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#packaged-dags) and came up with the following idea:

- Depending on the branch (develop vs. master), CircleCI creates zip folders with an extra info in the name depending on the stage, so that in `usr/local/airflow/dags` I have two zip folders, e.g. `test_staging.zip` and `test_production.zip` both containing other python files. Within the dag file I can modify the DAG id depending on the stage so that both are loaded.
- The problem seems to be: The other external python files in the zip folder have the same name but different content (depending on the branch) and only one (the one that is loaded first) is available in airflow.

This is not an solution, but illustrates that this way it seems not possible to manage different stages using packaged DAGs. However, maybe I am missing a point regarding this idea?